# Using collective.geo.behaviour and dexterity cause site failure

Tags: geolocation, plone, zope, dexterity

I have a strange problem when I attempt to use collective.geo.behavior with my dexterity content type (named profilmembre). I used the filesystem way to create content type (not TTW).

Without collective.geo.behavior I can create profilmembre inside Plone site's root or as any folder child. That's right.

With collective.geo.behavior behaviour I can create profilmembre inside Plone site's root but if create this content-type inside a classic Folder my plone site crashed with (in browser):

`ValueError('No object with id "" exists.',) (Also, the following error occurred while attempting to render the standard error message, please see the event log for full details: No object with id "" exists.)`

This message doesn't appear only for content view but for entire site (which is broken)

To restore, I need making "Clear and rebuild" in portal_catalog. Permitting me seeing memberprofil and folder content while I created memberprofil once again

(projet on github :  https://github.com/tristanlt/iuem.cargo )

Here is the debug trace after content creation :

```
  Module zope.contentprovider.tales, line 77, in __call__
  Module zope.viewlet.manager, line 112, in update
  Module zope.viewlet.manager, line 118, in _updateViewlets
  Module plone.app.layout.viewlets.common, line 187, in update
  Module Products.CMFPlone.browser.navigation, line 183, in topLevelTabs
  Module Products.CMFPlone.CatalogTool, line 428, in searchResults
  Module Products.ZCatalog.ZCatalog, line 604, in searchResults
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 907, in searchResults
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 656, in search
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 676, in sortResults
  Module plone.app.folder.nogopip, line 104, in documentToKeyMap
  Module plone.folder.ordered, line 102, in getObjectPosition
  Module plone.folder.default, line 128, in getObjectPosition
ValueError: No object with id "" exists.
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this commit fix your problem:

- https://github.com/collective/collective.geo.geographer/commit/d950d7ade1d348e77e66dfa1217c53bf2dea20f0

Using Dexterity, the context of GeoreferencingAnnotator was wrapped by Acquisition. 
Now I have unwrapped the context with Acquisition.aq_base

Comment: I've reverted that commit bacause it raises some errors with c.geo.contentlocations. The fix has ben moved to c.geo.behavior - https://github.com/collective/collective.geo.behaviour/commit/e25ef7085f173c9c9f6607ca7a5a3984f990c94d